# Correct way to find proportion of events in quartiles

Tags: proportion, quantiles

I am analyzing data on proportion of events occurring with respect to blood levels of chemical. The data is of 400 persons. They have been divided in 4 quartiles (100 persons in each quartile) based on the blood level of the chemical. So in first quartile, 2 out of 100 had events while in 4th quartile, 8 of 100 persons had events.

I found that there are 2 ways to find proportion of events in each quartile: Proportion of the number of persons in that quartile vs proportion of total events:

```
quartile    N   event   Proportion_of_N     Proportion_of_total_events
1           100     2   2.0% (2/100)        11.1% (2/18)
2           100     3   3.0% (3/100)        16.7% (3/18)
3           100     5   5.0% (5/100)        27.8% (5/18)
4           100     8   8.0% (8/100)        44.4% (8/18)
            
total:      400     18  18.0%           100.0%
```

The method of calculating proportion is shown in brackets.

Though both methods show an increasing proportion with increasing quartile, the actual value of proportions are quite different in the two methods. Which of the above is the correct method to analyze and report proportions in quartiles?

Comment: Do you mind sharing with us what these two methods are?

Comment: I have clarified in the question above.

Comment: So what is `N` and `event`, what do they represent? Also, why is the total N equal to 400, yet you divide by 100?

Comment: I have clarified in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either could be correct depending on what you want. Let me twist your example but keep it concrete: I take the unspecified event to be death from Covid if infected.

Then the

- overall probability of death is 18/400, which is 4.5% or 0.045 (**not** 18%)
- the probability of death given that someone is in a particular quartile (I'd prefer to say quartile bin, or quarter, but whether terminology is good or bad is a different story) is variously 2, 3, 5, or 8% (or 0.02, 0.03, 0.05 or 0.08)
- the probability that a dead person comes from a particular quartile bin is variously 2, 3, 5 or 8 out of 18.

Probabilities here are all fractions calculated as ratios, count of event in subset / number in subset; and different definitions of subsets typically mean different results. The probability of being a cat given being a mammal is what it is (in a zoo, likely to be small but not zero), but the probability of being a mammal given being a cat is identically 1.